# Print In Asp .Net With C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Recently I Have work in A Project Education Management System Which Is On Windows Application Using C#.net In That I am Use Print document Control To Print Mark sheet Layout And It work well.. But I Have To Convert It On Asp.net Web Site So Any Printing Method Which Print Mark sheet Layout Same Quality As Print Document And Content Of Mark sheet Fatch From Database. 
Any Code Which Is Help Full To Print In C# , Java Script .  Any code related to printing but print quality is necessary because of mark sheet printing

I have code its window appilcation Related Code But I Want Web Based Solution

```
private void printDocument2_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, rectangleShape1.Location.X, rectangleShape1.Location.Y, rectangleShape1.Width, rectangleShape1.Height);
        //////////////////////////////
        e.Graphics.DrawString(label24.Text, label24.Font, Brushes.DarkBlue, label24.Location.X, label24.Location.Y);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(label25.Text, label25.Font, Brushes.DarkBlue, label25.Location.X, label25.Location.Y);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(label26.Text, label26.Font, Brushes.Brown, label26.Location.X, label26.Location.Y);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(label27.Text, label27.Font, Brushes.Black , label27.Location.X, label27.Location.Y);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(label28.Text, label28.Font, Brushes.Black, label28.Location.X, label28.Location.Y);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(label29.Text, label29.Font, Brushes.Black, label29.Location.X, label29.Location.Y);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(label30.Text, label30.Font, Brushes.Black, label30.Location.X, label30.Location.Y);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(label31.Text, label31.Font, Brushes.Black, label31.Location.X, label31.Location.Y);
         ////////////////////////////
        e.Graphics.DrawString(txtRollno.Text, txtRollno.Font, Brushes.Black, txtRollno.Location.X, txtRollno.Location.Y);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(txtName.Text, txtName.Font, Brushes.Black, txtName.Location.X, txtName.Location.Y);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(txtfathernameid.Text, txtfathernameid.Font, Brushes.Black, txtfathernameid.Location.X, txtfathernameid.Location.Y);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(txtAddress.Text, txtAddress.Font, Brushes.Black, txtAddress.Location.X, txtAddress.Location.Y);
        e.Graphics.DrawString(txtContact.Text, txtContact.Font, Brushes.Black, txtContact.Location.X, txtContact.Location.Y);
    ////////////////
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(pictureBox1.Image, pictureBox1.Location.X, pictureBox1.Location.Y, pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
    }


 private void btnPrintPreview2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        printPreviewDialog1.Document = printDocument2;
        printPreviewDialog1.Show Dialog();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no control available in ASP.Net like the one in Window version of .Net. A possible approach is to first render your report/document as PDF/Word or XLS and then print. There are number of open source project out there to create PDF/XLS files on the fly my favorite is **http://pdfsharp.com/**, lately on top of PDFsharp lib they have added MigraDoc library which is very helpful in creating PDF documents and printing them.

Comment: Thanks For The reply but i listen than we can also print HTML page through java script so any java scrip code for print

Comment: Yes you can print HTML, its pretty simple, just call window.print(), http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_print.asp. For better results you may need to created a separate css stylesheet for print media.

Answer (score 1):

To print the page in javascript you'd use:

```
window.print();
```